# Shapely multiline string to shapefile as single line

Tags: python, shapely, linestring

I am using shapely [unary_union](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) to dissolve multiple line strings to one line before exporting to a shapefile.

The output from unary_union is a multiline string (example below which you can paste into [Wicket](https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html)). When exported to a shapefile it has multiple features, not a single line feature. The lines will also be contiguous and won't crossover.

I wish to export a single line to a shapefile.

Any ideas how I can convert this multilinestring to a single line to export to a shapefile using Python?

```
MULTILINESTRING ((-0.09949110399971201 51.5155806841531, -0.09939409904597001 51.5155866836785), (-0.09939409904597001 51.5155866836785, -0.099157101257869 51.5156026798101, -0.09894309853312901 51.5156136796089, -0.098606089003514 51.5156396806721), (-0.110974258419515 51.5160386692171, -0.110238251143733 51.5160786768392, -0.110021240981987 51.5160836790967, -0.10920123172948 51.5160436761356), (-0.100489111082423 51.5158396976804, -0.100147103216365 51.515751692648, -0.100005104816976 51.5157156867549, -0.099705101703361 51.5156386848511, -0.09949110399971201 51.5155806841531), (-0.096948042611141 51.5162726881509, -0.096809042170933 51.5163016817966, -0.096766045170016 51.5163096798522, -0.096646035155609 51.516306679561, -0.096536034520283 51.5162796780959, -0.09599703639863801 51.5160726720984), (-0.10920123172948 51.5160436761356, -0.108946235222691 51.5159406814919), (-0.098606089003514 51.5156396806721, -0.098581080324168 51.5159856856925), (-0.098581080324168 51.5159856856925, -0.098579085793847 51.5160186837986), (-0.101631124099211 51.5161287050545, -0.101345125778253 51.5160607023621, -0.100489111082423 51.5158396976804), (-0.108946235222691 51.5159406814919, -0.108427215046776 51.5163006848396, -0.108233217600768 51.5164566927597), (-0.10189812477131 51.5162747066834, -0.101635127398062 51.5161617104127, -0.101631124099211 51.5161287050545), (-0.09756804878370801 51.5168587005634, -0.097378042105961 51.5168537018865), (-0.105628154794541 51.5174297237828, -0.105285153672418 51.5173207230403), (-0.105825165458289 51.5174827247051, -0.105628154794541 51.5174297237828), (-0.106150163502194 51.5175487266679, -0.105825165458289 51.5174827247051), (-0.107501647389745 51.5177349595282, -0.107340171401701 51.517729728669, -0.106975176646835 51.5176907283359), (-0.106626162493138 51.5176407258543, -0.106341172817837 51.5175897234412, -0.106155168677775 51.5175507229232, -0.106150163502194 51.5175487266679), (-0.106975176646835 51.5176907283359, -0.106784171150247 51.5176687253487, -0.106626162493138 51.5176407258543), (-0.107966196562356 51.5169177085558, -0.10799419951621 51.5169487086171, -0.107991194093993 51.5169687050333), (-0.105285153672418 51.5173207230403, -0.105043150976977 51.5172627229313), (-0.107991194093993 51.5169687050333, -0.107955188123035 51.5171947151563, -0.107827192698567 51.5175737187894, -0.107752187450459 51.5176407280537, -0.107620186230955 51.5176727263747, -0.107501647389745 51.5177349595282), (-0.09599703639863801 51.5160726720984, -0.09565201332232399 51.5167506891305), (-0.108233217600768 51.5164566927597, -0.108143207289198 51.5165296924142), (-0.102908143089807 51.5166167176979, -0.102566136130494 51.516508713858, -0.102125132159789 51.5163697100862, -0.102097126506935 51.5163607138707, -0.10189812477131 51.5162747066834), (-0.09684403151146299 51.5168507003487, -0.096917047040718 51.5164926876091, -0.096948042611141 51.5162726881509), (-0.098579085793847 51.5160186837986, -0.098577075996562 51.5160786869506, -0.098523075572903 51.5163296987367, -0.09851506315709301 51.5166507006444), (-0.09565201332232399 51.5167506891305, -0.095124002251253 51.5166336771743, -0.095038011838352 51.5166146812559), (-0.108143207289198 51.5165296924142, -0.108067207437454 51.516627702025, -0.108004200620196 51.5167617033692, -0.107966196562356 51.5169177085558), (-0.097378042105961 51.5168537018865, -0.097303044257364 51.5168506952598, -0.097278040842032 51.5168346960399, -0.0972490383143 51.5168236948407, -0.097226045725422 51.5168216940064, -0.09720304771133 51.516825700246, -0.097183044487221 51.5168366974981, -0.09716203615346999 51.5168597017592, -0.096969034909765 51.516856695177), (-0.097740048796003 51.5167776967244, -0.097643044636673 51.5168047018443, -0.097597040695186 51.5168256999103, -0.09756804878370801 51.5168587005634), (-0.096969034909765 51.516856695177, -0.09684403151146299 51.5168507003487), (-0.105043150976977 51.5172627229313, -0.104872152536407 51.5172147272079, -0.104701153906309 51.5171577204369, -0.104530157078847 51.5171017205277, -0.104389153408835 51.5170447211936, -0.104261154722598 51.517006717753, -0.104032144721189 51.5169677202329, -0.102908143089807 51.5166167176979), (-0.09851506315709301 51.5166507006444, -0.098516066683921 51.516674700639), (-0.098516066683921 51.516674700639, -0.09834305848463699 51.5166906985632), (-0.09834305848463699 51.5166906985632, -0.098296060979841 51.5167397022699, -0.098132056239479 51.5167526984394, -0.097987060249468 51.5167367043092, -0.09787504867437299 51.5167337001089), (-0.09787504867437299 51.5167337001089, -0.097834057950725 51.5167437005148, -0.097740048796003 51.5167776967244))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html) (what are you using ?) to export the MultiLineString to a shapefile, **the results is a shapefile with a single feature** (the shapefile format does not know the "MultiLineString" geometry, replaced by a list of polyline geometries).

[image]

```
from shapely.wkt import loads
multi = loads("MULTILINESTRING ((-0.09949110399971201 51.5155806841531, -0.09939409904597001 51.5155866836785), (-0.09939409904597001 51.5155866836785, -0.099157101257869 51.5156026798101, -0.09894309853312901 51.5156136796089, -0.098606089003514 51.5156396806721), (-0.110974258419515 51.5160386692171, -0.110238251143733 51.5160786768392, -0.110021240981987 51.5160836790967, -0.10920123172948 51.5160436761356), (-0.100489111082423 51.5158396976804, -0.100147103216365 51.515751692648, -0.100005104816976 51.5157156867549, -0.099705101703361 51.5156386848511, -0.09949110399971201 51.5155806841531), (-0.096948042611141 51.5162726881509, -0.096809042170933 51.5163016817966, -0.096766045170016 51.5163096798522, -0.096646035155609 51.516306679561, -0.096536034520283 51.5162796780959, -0.09599703639863801 51.5160726720984), (-0.10920123172948 51.5160436761356, -0.108946235222691 51.5159406814919), (-0.098606089003514 51.5156396806721, -0.098581080324168 51.5159856856925), (-0.098581080324168 51.5159856856925, -0.098579085793847 51.5160186837986), (-0.101631124099211 51.5161287050545, -0.101345125778253 51.5160607023621, -0.100489111082423 51.5158396976804), (-0.108946235222691 51.5159406814919, -0.108427215046776 51.5163006848396, -0.108233217600768 51.5164566927597), (-0.10189812477131 51.5162747066834, -0.101635127398062 51.5161617104127, -0.101631124099211 51.5161287050545), (-0.09756804878370801 51.5168587005634, -0.097378042105961 51.5168537018865), (-0.105628154794541 51.5174297237828, -0.105285153672418 51.5173207230403), (-0.105825165458289 51.5174827247051, -0.105628154794541 51.5174297237828), (-0.106150163502194 51.5175487266679, -0.105825165458289 51.5174827247051), (-0.107501647389745 51.5177349595282, -0.107340171401701 51.517729728669, -0.106975176646835 51.5176907283359), (-0.106626162493138 51.5176407258543, -0.106341172817837 51.5175897234412, -0.106155168677775 51.5175507229232, -0.106150163502194 51.5175487266679), (-0.106975176646835 51.5176907283359, -0.106784171150247 51.5176687253487, -0.106626162493138 51.5176407258543), (-0.107966196562356 51.5169177085558, -0.10799419951621 51.5169487086171, -0.107991194093993 51.5169687050333), (-0.105285153672418 51.5173207230403, -0.105043150976977 51.5172627229313), (-0.107991194093993 51.5169687050333, -0.107955188123035 51.5171947151563, -0.107827192698567 51.5175737187894, -0.107752187450459 51.5176407280537, -0.107620186230955 51.5176727263747, -0.107501647389745 51.5177349595282), (-0.09599703639863801 51.5160726720984, -0.09565201332232399 51.5167506891305), (-0.108233217600768 51.5164566927597, -0.108143207289198 51.5165296924142), (-0.102908143089807 51.5166167176979, -0.102566136130494 51.516508713858, -0.102125132159789 51.5163697100862, -0.102097126506935 51.5163607138707, -0.10189812477131 51.5162747066834), (-0.09684403151146299 51.5168507003487, -0.096917047040718 51.5164926876091, -0.096948042611141 51.5162726881509), (-0.098579085793847 51.5160186837986, -0.098577075996562 51.5160786869506, -0.098523075572903 51.5163296987367, -0.09851506315709301 51.5166507006444), (-0.09565201332232399 51.5167506891305, -0.095124002251253 51.5166336771743, -0.095038011838352 51.5166146812559), (-0.108143207289198 51.5165296924142, -0.108067207437454 51.516627702025, -0.108004200620196 51.5167617033692, -0.107966196562356 51.5169177085558), (-0.097378042105961 51.5168537018865, -0.097303044257364 51.5168506952598, -0.097278040842032 51.5168346960399, -0.0972490383143 51.5168236948407, -0.097226045725422 51.5168216940064, -0.09720304771133 51.516825700246, -0.097183044487221 51.5168366974981, -0.09716203615346999 51.5168597017592, -0.096969034909765 51.516856695177), (-0.097740048796003 51.5167776967244, -0.097643044636673 51.5168047018443, -0.097597040695186 51.5168256999103, -0.09756804878370801 51.5168587005634), (-0.096969034909765 51.516856695177, -0.09684403151146299 51.5168507003487), (-0.105043150976977 51.5172627229313, -0.104872152536407 51.5172147272079, -0.104701153906309 51.5171577204369, -0.104530157078847 51.5171017205277, -0.104389153408835 51.5170447211936, -0.104261154722598 51.517006717753, -0.104032144721189 51.5169677202329, -0.102908143089807 51.5166167176979), (-0.09851506315709301 51.5166507006444, -0.098516066683921 51.516674700639), (-0.098516066683921 51.516674700639, -0.09834305848463699 51.5166906985632), (-0.09834305848463699 51.5166906985632, -0.098296060979841 51.5167397022699, -0.098132056239479 51.5167526984394, -0.097987060249468 51.5167367043092, -0.09787504867437299 51.5167337001089), (-0.09787504867437299 51.5167337001089, -0.097834057950725 51.5167437005148, -0.097740048796003 51.5167776967244))")
import loads
from shapely.geometry import mapping
# schema of the resulting shapefile
schema = {'geometry': 'MultiLineString','properties': {'id': 'int'}}
# save 
with fiona.open('multiline.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema)  as output:
     output.write({'geometry':mapping(multi),'properties': {'id':1}})
```

Now open the resulting shapefile

```
 result = fiona.open('multiline.shp')
 # schema
 print result
 {'geometry': 'LineString', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 'int:10')])}
 # number of features
 print "number= ", len(result)
 number=  1
 # the feature
 feat = result.next()
 print feat['geometry']['type']
 MultiLineString
```

If you absolutely want a LineString (with [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952))

```
multicoords = [list(line.coords) for line in multi]
# Making a flat list -> LineString
simple = LineString([item for sublist in multicoords  for item in sublist])
# resulting shapefile
schema = {'geometry': 'LineString','properties': {'id': 'int'}}
with fiona.open('line.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema)  as output:
   output.write({'geometry':mapping(a),'properties': {'id':1}})
```

Control

```
result = fiona.open('line.shp')
print len(result)
1
feat = result.next()
print feat['geometry']['type']
LineString
```